# Should outlets have getters/setters?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder

Should I better **always** write

```
    @interface MyClass
    {
        NSTextField * myTextField ;
    }
    @property (assign)  NSTextField * myTextField ;
```

or just

```
    @interface MyClass
    {
        NSTextField * myTextField ;
    }
```

?

Why I have reasons to think that we should add the `@property` line :

- I recently had a program which won't work if the outlet did not have a getter/setter.
- Plus : we found the following line when a project is created

  ```
  @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
  ```

Comment: IBOutlets are only applicable to properties. There is very little need to use iVars in your header of your class anymore, either put it in a class extension or in your @implementation.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment please ? What's an iVar ? Plus : I have always been told/shown to declare the attributes of a class in the `.h`. Do you only mean that if there is a `@property` then I don't need to declare the attribute before ?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, while I'm nitpicking, your first sentence is wrong. IBOutlets can be used to decorate an instance variable, even without a corresponding `@property`. This was the normal (only) way to do things in pre-Objective-C 2.0, and still works. 100% agree with your second sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the property for Interface Builder using `IBOutlet`. If you're not using Interface Builder you don't need `IBOutlet`. If you're not using Interface Builder you may not even need a property at all (properties are generally public, while instance variables are always private).

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField ;
```

You don't need to create an instance variable or synthesize it as its done for you.

You can access it with `self.myTextField` in your code.

Comment: So, what's the use of `@synthetize` ?

Comment: `@synthesize` used to automatically create getters/setters for your properties. Itself was a shortcut. But now `@synthesize` has been turned on automatically for your properties as of Xcode 4.4

Comment: Instance variables are not always private. They're private by default, but can be made public or protected as well.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen is right that they can be public. I mean as a consumer of the code. Other classes can never access an instance variable where as a property they can. It was silly of my to use that terminology.

Comment: Plus : Xcode (4.2) asks me to implement the methode, or to use `@synthesize` or `@dynamic`...

Comment: In Xcode 4.2 you will need `@synthesize` but you should definitely consider updating to the latest build of Xcode. You should always do your best to produce apps using the latest version of your most important tool.

Comment: Thanks @RyanPoolos for your advice. I am working on a early '09 macMini and dont know if it worths buying a new computer. Mountain Lion does not work on my computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Xcode 4.4 supports 10.7 and up just FYI. But I do understand those constraints. Atleast now you know what `@synthesize` is for and can look forward to the day you no longer need it. :)

Comment: @RyanPoolos, actually if an ivar is public, other classes *can* access it. That's what public means. That said, that's almost never a good idea, and `@properties` should always be used to publicly expose a class's attributes, as you've indicated.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you create a `property` for an outlet object or any other object then ivar is created for it (in new compilers).

Now creating ivars and properties are obsolete.
Even `property` are matched up with auto-synthesizes.

If you really want ivars then you can put it in `.m` file or if you want them to be private then add an extension to the class with them.

> Should outlet have setter/getter

Yes indeed you need to access them many times. Like checking the state of Radio button, check box, setting stringValue  is NSTextField, reloading table by [tableView reloadData] etc.

```
@interface MyClass
    {
        NSTextField * myTextField ; //this is ivar
    }
    @property (assign)  NSTextField * myTextField ; //this is property
@end
```

Whatever you put in `.h` is `public` and accessible, if you want to make it hidden do it in `.m` even within an extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "Even property creates auto-synthesizes the objects." ?

Comment: I thought we had to create iVars in the `.h` ? Is what you say a new fashion ? (I am a beginner)

Comment: @Colas: check my edited answer, and you can avail the new feature of XCode4.4+ compilers on osx10.7+

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefers, if you require your object reference scope, outside the class then go with property declaration. Otherwise declare it as instance variable inside the class brackets and that to in implementation file. (if you are not inheriting this variable feature further)

So,

- If you require to access your variable instance outside the class then declare property. In MyClassViewController.h header file

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;`

So now in other classes, one can access this by:

```
MyClassViewController *myClassViewController = [[MyClassViewController alloc] init];
[myClassViewController.myTextField setText:@"MyValue"];
```

also get value like

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myClassViewController.myTextField text]);
```

- If you don't want such public access, but you want it to get inherited. Then declare in class declaration block itself. In ViewController.h header file

  ```
  @interface ViewController { @public: // or @protected
    NSString *myString;
  }
  ```

Now if there is another class which inherits ViewController class then this property will get inherited in ChildViewController according to its access specifier.

- If you want completely hidden property or variable. Like its not even being used outside of that class itself, then you can declare it in implementation file (.m) in private category itself. In ViewController.m file:

`@interface ViewController () {`

```
  NSString *myString;
}
```

So this will be having visibility in .m file only, nowhere else.

Now declaration of `@property`- You require to declare this only when you require setter-getter default methods (Like setMyString etc). This also you can declare in both .h as well in .m according to your visibility requirement of that instance.

Hope now you are getting the concept. Its all about visibility.

Comment: My question was specific to outlets !!! Anyway, it is a nice answer. Why not use `@private` instead of creating a category ?

Comment: Yes you are right in this matter, even I myself have the same question. But if you download any latest code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code
Apple itself is using this methodology. So its better to go with Apple.